# Read custom user control state

Tags: asp.net

I add a custom user control to my page, with textboxes and radioboxes, but after each postback, the contents are removed and I don't know how to read the values that were entered in it.

From what I've learned you have to add the user controls on each refresh, but that does not restore their state. I want the values to be stored in the ViewState but that does not happen for some reason.

Note: I need to add multiple user controls on one page, so I need to identify each user control, either trough an ID or a linq expression that selects that user control from my page.

Im programming with C# 4.0

How I add my user control:

```
    private void AddInstrumentDetailToPage()
    {
        RMAItem lItem = (RMAItem)Page.LoadControl("/Controls/RMAItem.ascx");
        InstrumentDetail.Controls.Add(lItem);
    }
```

I save the amount of controls I have in the ViewState, and call AddInstrumentDetail() that amount of times, but they appear to be empty. I've read somewhere that I have to add it in Page_Init because view state is not initialised yet, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: how are you adding your user control? is it feasible to add it in aspx code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate dynamically added (User-)Controls at latest in `Page_Load` to maintain ViewState. So you should store the number of already added controls in a ViewState-Property and according to that reload them in `Page_Load`. You have to sum up this variable with 1 in `AddInstrumentDetailToPage`.

[MSDN: Dynamically Adding User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx#usercontrols_topic10)

If you store the number of added controls in a Viewstate variable, you cannot recreate controls in Page's Init-Event because the ViewState-Variable would yet not been reloaded there.

Comment: I save the amount of controls I have in the ViewState, and call AddInstrumentDetail() that amount of times, but they appear to be empty. I've read somewhere that I have to add it in Page_Init because view state is not initialised yet, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Ah! I uderstand, I have to add the control in Page_Init, but how do I know how many I have to add? Can I just save it in a querystring or something?

Comment: It could be sufficient in Page_Load(with the advantage of using a ViewState variable to store the number of added controls). Have a look at following article to see when it's sufficient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4 or another anwer of me on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046101/dynamically-created-controls-are-wiped-out-on-button-click/5046162#5046162

Comment: You've answered my question. And if it's not too much trouble, one quick question: How can I get a list of the controls I added in an event function without creating a member variable? like GetControls only for RMAItems.

Comment: Ah I got it! I just loop over the values in InstrumentDetails.Controls and check if it is an RMAItem.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correctly. You need this property if you want to reload the controls on postback. So how do you want to count the number of `RMAItems` in Page_Init or Page_Load if it's always 0 because you haven't yet recreated them?

Answer (score 1):

You won't have any `ControlState` unless you make a `PostBack`. Refreshing your browser/requesting the same link will just be a fresh start.

By default, any `control` added to your page are data stored in `ViewState` and `ControlState` for your `UserControl`.

If you are willing to save your contents, I would suggest you save it on `Request.Session.Add("yourKey", "yourValue")`.

You can access your session with `var yourValue = Request.Session["yourKey"];` on your `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method.

Specify an ID for your `RMAItem` instance, otherwise storing data on `ControlState` might not work!

```
private void AddInstrumentDetailToPage()
{
    RMAItem lItem = (RMAItem)Page.LoadControl("/Controls/RMAItem.ascx");
    lItem.ID = "rmaItem1"; //<-- This is important
    InstrumentDetail.Controls.Add(lItem);
}
```

Hope it helps!