# Events in my dynamically loaded user controls do not fire in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have ASP.NET Web Application that contains MasterPage, ASPX Page where I load User Controls dynamically into UpdatePanel containing PlaceHolder based on menu selection. This works fine. The problem is that no events in my User Controls work.. I have different scenarios:

1. DropDownList, where selected value should load different UserControls
2. LinkButton, where Click event should load different UserControl into the PlaceHolder (on the parent page).

I have spent 3 days on this now and tried several things for this.... Registered events, used Interface among other things....

but so far nothing has worked :( ..thankful for any help I can get.

Yes, i have tried Page_PreInit event on the User Control as well. 
The only thing that fires when I click my LinkButton (or DropDownList) in my user control is the Page_Load event on the parent page..and then the PlaceHolder containing the user control (i am clicking) has Contol.Count = null
Here is some code

```
//Page_Load on parent page:

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadDefaultControl(ctrlPlaceHolder, Base_Path + "_Services.ascx");
        }
    }
```

//Page_Load in my Usercontrol

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btJoomlaManagement.Click += btJoomlaManagement_Click;
    }
```

The PlaceHolder on the parent page is inside a UpdatePanel >> ContentTemplate.

```
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlControlContainer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ctrlPlaceHolder" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="menuServices" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The behavior is following..when I load my USerControl Page_Load with the Click event runs..when I click my Linkbutton in my usercontrol, Page_Load on the parent page runs but not my Click method in my usercontrol. The usercontrol (that I just clicked my Linkbutton on) disappears.

So my event (click) does not fire... hope you understand a little better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-create dynamic control on every single postback, remember the Page instance is created per request, if you do not re-create the control then it wont exist on PostBack.

Of course your control disappears, you didnt re-create it on the postback.

see [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

**Extract**:

> Dynamically added controls must be programmatically added to the Web
>   page on each and every page visit. The best time to add these controls
>   is during the initialization stage of the page life cycle, which
>   occurs before the load view state stage. That is, we want to have the
>   control hierarchy complete before the load view state stage arrives.
>   For this reason, it is best to create an event handler for the Page
>   class's Init event in your code-behind class, and add your dynamic
>   controls there.

Comment: I do not want to recreate the control again..I want to load new control into the placeholder on the parent page. Do I have to recreate the control then?

Comment: You have to re-create your control on each postback, otherwise where is it going to come from ? The `Page` instance you are dealing with is a new instance and does not know anything about what controls you created in the original instance.see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046101/dynamically-created-controls-are-wiped-out-on-button-click

Comment: I believe this is probably the correct answer.  Its difficult to understand at first, but the page lifecycle should help you understand.  When you click your whole page posts back, so the control is then gone and the event no longer exists.

Comment: @RichardFriend the link is unavailable, please add new link and/or update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching the event in the Page_Init event instead of the Page_Load? This is how I do event assignment in my dynamic-control applications, haven't had any problems with that. Also, you mention this is being done in an UpdatePanel, is it in the content template? If so, are you adding appropriate triggers to it (If indeed you want this to happen in an AJAX manner)?

Are you setting the "autopostback" property to true?

Seeing some code would definitely help...

Comment: Yes, i have tried Page_PreInit event on the User Control as well. 
The only thing that fires when I click my LinkButton (or DropDownList) in my user control is the Page_Load event on the parent page..and then the PlaceHolder containing the user control (i am clicking) has Contol.Count = null

Here is some code
<code></code>