# Dynamically load user controls on button click, postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to load usercontrols on button click, but problem is that, it disappears on postback inside user control.

this is how i load controls:

```
private bool IsUserControl
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["IsUserControl"] != null)
        {
            return (bool)ViewState["IsUserControl"];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["IsUserControl"] = value;
    }
}


#region Usercontrols
private void CreateUserControlAllNews()
{
    Control featuredProduct = Page.LoadControl("path/usercontrol.ascx");
    plh1.Controls.Add(featuredProduct);
}

#endregion
protected void allNewsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.IsUserControl = true;
    if(IsUserControl)
    CreateUserControlAllNews();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reload the control when the page is post back. For example,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsUserControl)
    {
        CreateUserControlAllNews();        
    }
}

private void CreateUserControlAllNews()
{
    Control featuredProduct = Page.LoadControl("path/usercontrol.ascx");
    featuredProduct.ID = "1234";
    plh1.Controls.Add(featuredProduct);
}
```

Comment: thx for help. but the problem is that i have menu like linkbuttons and i want to load different usercontrols on each click. if i load controls on each postback, they will all  stay on screen. sorry for my bad English, hope you'll understand my post.

Comment: I answered similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14449305/296861. If type of controls are mixed, you need to store SortedDictionary in ViewState instead of List<int>.

Answer (score 1):

OF course it disappears, every request creates a brand new instance of your page and if you dont re-create the control on that postback then it wont exist.

See the following links about this very common issue.

[Singing eels](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914692/events-in-my-dynamically-loaded-user-controls-do-not-fire-in-asp-net-web-applica/8926355#8926355)