# PostBack and function issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Not using jQuery or Javascript as this is a fix of an existing site and it was not designed that way. Well I have gotten to a point where when the DropDownList is selected and does it's postBack I do my logic of setting the textBox readOnly status to true or false. the problem I have now is the the selectValue is not consistant. Wht it show in the selct field is not what is posted back to the page. Say I have None, 5.00, 10.00, 15.00, 20.00 as my choices to choose. I first choose 10.00 and it posts back None then I choose 20.00 it shows 10.00. It posts back the prior select value. the entire site is written from the code behind page. the aspx page is completely written from the .vb page. Everything is written into asp tags.  here is the code;

```
            If Page.IsPostBack Then
                If product_option_is_required > 0 then
                    myTextBox.ReadOnly= true
                Else
                    myTextBox.ReadOnly= false
                End if
                For Each child_control As Control In productOptions.Controls
                    If TypeOf child_control Is DropDownList Then
                        Dim child_ddl As DropDownList = child_control
                        tempName = products.getProductDependant("product_option_name",product_option_id)
                        tempSelectText = products.getProductSelectDependant("product_option_detail_name",child_ddl.SelectedValue)
                        priceDependant.Text ="here" & child_ddl.ID & " " & child_ddl.SelectedIndex & " " & child_ddl.SelectedValue & " --" & tempSelectText
                        If child_ddl.Text = "None" then
                            myTextBox.ReadOnly = true
                            myTextBox.Text = "If selected above enter name"
                        Else
                            myTextBox.ReadOnly = false
                            myTextBox.Text = ""
                        End if
                    End If

                next
            End if
```

Comment: Why do you use a select instead of a ASP.NET `DropDownList`? You could handle it's `SelectedIndexChanged` Event instead of using `Page_Load`.

Comment: it is a dropdownList I just used the words select field sorry. The system writes the __doPostBack and I capture that process and run my code at that time.

Comment: You know what you need to recreate all dynamic controls on postbacks with the same ID as before in Page_Load at the latest?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Page_Load is too late. Page_Init is the latest you can recreate dynamic controls.

Comment: @ShaiCohen:  _"When you create dynamic controls on a Web Form, you must create the controls and add them to the controls collection in either the Page_Init event handler **or the Page_Load event handler**. Otherwise, the controls may not behave as expected."_ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515/EN-US

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Looks like you are correct. Strange though, I always thought Page_Init was the latest event to recreate dynamic controls. Just wondering, was it always this way, or is _catch-up_ a feature that was implemented in a later version of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using dependantProd like a string value.

```
dependantProd = tempName.Replace(" ", "_") & "_" & product_option_id
```

If it is a string, you can't do like this -

> If dependantProd.SelectedIndex > 0 then

Besides, if you dynamically create a control, you need to retrieve in post back. Otherwise, you won't be able retrieve their posted value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462040/296861

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14449305/296861