# find control at runtime

Tags: asp.net

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload F = new FileUpload { ID = "FF" };
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(F);

    }

     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload FU = (FileUpload)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("FF");
        Label1.Text = Fu.filename;
      }
```

so i cant find the fileupload at run time

Comment: but i want to create it at runtime

Answer (score 3):

You must recreate dynamically created controls on **every** postback.
So store the number of already created controls in ViewState or Session and recreate them during Page_Init or Page_Load(at the latest). Assign the same ID as before so that events are triggered correctly and values can be reloaded from ViewState.

- [Dynamically created controls are wiped out on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046101/dynamically-created-controls-are-wiped-out-on-button-click/5046162#5046162) (repeating myself)
- [Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
- [Dynamically Created Controls in ASP.NET](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

For example:

```
private Int32 ControlCount {
    get {
        if (ViewState("ControlCount") == null) {
            ViewState("ControlCount") = 0;
        }
        return (Int32)ViewState("ControlCount");
    }
    set { ViewState("ControlCount") = value; }
}

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (ControlCount != 0) {
        RecreateControls();
    }
}

private void RecreateControls()
{
    addControls(ControlCount);
}

private void addControls(Int32 count)
{
    for (Int32 i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        FileUpload F = new FileUpload { ID = "FF_" + i };
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(F);
    }
}


Protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    addControls(1);
    ControlCount ++;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( ControlCount != 0 ){
        // find for example the first FileUpload control
        var index = 1;
        FileUpload FF1 = (FileUpload)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("FF_" + index);
        Label1.Text = FF1.filename;
    }
 }
```

Comment: how to create validator on textbox at run time ,the textbox at runtime and the validator at runtime

Comment: I would recommend to wrap all in [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) so that you don't need to bother around with single controls. But apart from that, it works the same as described in my answer. You can create dynamically any type of control and as many as you want.