# Adding user control to a place holder on form not working on second postback

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Hi all I have a user control which I am loading it in a place holder and showing it on button click, for the first time it is working fine, but if I click on the button again code getting executed but the user control is not showing any help please

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        placeholder.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl1 usrcntrl= (UserControl1)LoadControl("~/UserControl.ascx");
        placeholder.Controls.Add(usrcntrl);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add only one or multiple of this control?

Comment: Only one user control

Comment: You have to recreate this control anyway. But i recommend to use a static control that you just make `Visible`. That's less complicated, more readable and even more efficient(since ASP.NET can handle ViewState of declarative controls better).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reacreate all dynamic control on every postback with the same ID as before and in `Page_Load` at the latest.

[TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/30/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-2_2900_.aspx)

Here's a possible implementation to store the number of already created controls via `ViewState`: [find control at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275969/find-control-at-runtime/9276160#9276160)

```
Q: Do you want to add only one or multiple of this control?
A: Only one user control
```

You have to recreate this control anyway. But i recommend to use a static control that you just make `Visible`. That's less complicated, more readable and even more efficient since ASP.NET can handle `ViewState` of declarative controls better.

[TRULY Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)