# Load UserControls in a table cell after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

having in my aspx page a table with only one row and 2 columns, like:

```
<table runat="server" id="MainTable">
<tr>
<td>

<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 1" ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 2" ID="btn2" OnClick="btn2_Click" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 3" ID="btn3" OnClick="btn3_Click" />

</td>

<td>
<%-- place the user control here -->
</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

is it possible to load an UserControl in the second cell at the click of every button?

For example, if I click Button1, has to be loaded UserControl1 in the second cell.
If I click Button2, userControl1 has to be descharged and has to be loaded userControl2, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Luigi

Answer (score 0):

You should not load the UserControl dynamically in this case. It's certainly better just to switch [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) of all controls. So add the three UserControls statically to the table-cell and make them `Visible="false"` initially. Then change these properties accordingly in each button's click event.

Answer (score 0):

to add a user control to the page is very straightforward, you load it like any any other control to the page:

```
MyUserControl myControl = (MyUserControl) Page.LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");

Page.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Comment: Where and when should it be done (at the latest), does it only be added once or on every postback, how do you know that it was already added, .... ? Not very helpful as long as none of these questions will be answered. Apart from that the OP asked explixitely to add it to a table-cell and not to the Page.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the idea to load it on the fly.

But you should load it only when required and dispose it once your are done or on the button click second time, dispose it and remove the control and then load it again...Otherwise it will always remain in your RAM....and can cause Memory Leaks..

**Sample HTML**

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="MainTable">
    <asp:TableRow>
         <asp:TableCell ID="cell1" runat="server">
             <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 1" ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
             <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 2" ID="btn2" OnClick="btn2_Click" />
             <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 3" ID="btn3" OnClick="btn3_Click" />
         </asp:TableCell>
         <asp:TableCell  ID="cell2" runat="server">
         </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

---

**On Button Click**

```
cell2.Controls.Add(Your User Control ID);
```

**EDIT - 1**

```
cell2.Controls.Clear();
cell2.Controls.Add(Your User Control ID);
```

Comment: All objects of a page are disposed at the end of the Page-Lifecycle, so there is no memory leak. And there is no benefit of dynamically created controls, it makes life simply a lot more difficult. In this case it's the wrong approach since the user cannot add controls to the page. He only can make them visible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046101/dynamically-created-controls-are-wiped-out-on-button-click/5046162#5046162

Comment: Yes, you are right @Tim, but the control memory will be alive(right from the beginning since page is loaded) and in your case until and unless the user do not navigate to another page. So better to load it on demand... and remove it on second or another button click and load it again...

Comment: No, **all** objects that belongs to the page(member variables,controls etc.) are disposed at the end of **this** page's lifecycle. So when the user sees the rendered page, it's not existing on the Server's memory anymore. That's the reason why **every** control(even static controls on aspx markup, but that happens automatically) must be recreated on postbacks. HTTP is stateless!

Comment: I have already agreed for the disposed matter. Thanks for knowledge sharing. **BUT** If you want to check the control ID in the table cell, which is already rendered, you can do it by using the code...`cell2.Controls[0]` This will give you the memory of the control. You can give it a try :).

Comment: @ Pankaj: I wanted only to clarify that a memory leak by not clearing the ControlCollection is impossible since it is already cleared after a Postback. So when user clicks f.e. `bt2` the UserControl previously added by `btn1` is not existing.

Comment: Please correct my first name.. :) I am again saying disposing matter is already resolved. Please dispose it :) :)

Comment: What UserControlID I have to write in the Add method? If I put the name of my usercontrol file (for example "myusercontrol" for  myusercontrol.ascx) does not compile.

Comment: create the instance of the usercontrol and pass it in add function,

Comment: Suppose your usercontrol class name is Ciupaz. Here is the code. `Ciupaz c = new Ciupaz(); cell2.Controls.Add(c);`

Comment: @Pankaj: UserControls must be created via [Page.LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) if you want to add them to the page's ControlCollection. `Ciupaz c = (Ciupaz)Page.LoadControl("Ciupaz.ascx");`

Comment: Will you like you show some links that describe this line please ? Thanks again