# asp.net getting dynamically created table content

Tags: c#, asp.net, row, cell

I have an asp:table created in my aspx file with just a header row.

In my page_load I keep adding rows/cells.

When I try:

```
Table table = tempUpdatePanel.FindControl("myTable") as Table;
```

`table` only has 1 row, the header row, even though it actually has/displays many more.

How to pick up on the remaining rows/cells?

Comment: _"When I try..."_ where and when do you try that?

Comment: In a button_Click() method. so when I click a button on the page.

Comment: You need to recreate these rows on postbacks(in page_load at the latest) manually. Where do you store the number of already created rows? I believe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046101/dynamically-created-controls-are-wiped-out-on-button-click/5046162#5046162

Comment: the number of rows is done in a timer_tick() method, is that not the same as in page_load?

Comment: The timer tick causes the page to postback from the client to the server. Now all previously created controls and variables are disposed(HTTP is stateless). So you need to know how many rows were already added and must be recreated now. Therefor you could persist the number of rows(an `int` variable)  in a ViewState or Session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding adding rows/cells dynamically, you have to do it before Page_InitComplete, otherwise viewstate will over-write your dynamically created data in subsequent postbacks..

To know more, go through [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: But I have no way of knowing in advance how many rows will get added. That happens in page_load so does it mean I cannot ever get those dynamically created rows?

Comment: @user1468537 you can also recreate the table as TimSchmelter commented